# Library not loaded: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I was trying to do gui programming in Python.I figured out that PySide is a good framework to start with.As i was running Python 2.7.2 i downloaded PySide 2.7 and tried running a sample app.I got QtCore Library not loaded error.

This is the error that i got..

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
Reason: image not found
```

I googled and found out that many people were facing the same issue and i saw solutions being posted based on exporting DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH. I was not able to follow this.
Could anyone please tell me whats the issue and how to fix it!!
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention the OS you are working on, but from the paths in your error message it looks like you're on Mac OSX.

I'm not an expert in PySide at all, but I had the same problem a while ago and I think I know what's going on: The library at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so` is the part that makes the Qt Core C++ library available to Python. It is just the wrapper though or some sort of translator between C++ and Python, the actual C++ functionality is elsewhere - and when the Python interpreter tries to load the C++ library that contains that functionality from `QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore`, if fails to find it, hence the error message.

A quick and dirty way to solve your problem is to create symbolic links from the location where `QtCore.so` expects the C++ library to where it actually is. For that, you will obviously have to find the C++ library. If you downloaded Qt 4.8.4 as an installer from the [Qt Project page](http://qt-project.org/downloads), the libraries AFAIK are somewhere in `/usr/lib`, so you would create a symlink like this:

```
ln -vis /usr/lib/<insert subfolder>/QtCore.framework /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.framework
```

You will have to do this in a similar way for QtGui and any other Qt library you want to use as well. Note that this obviously does not symlink the library itself, but the folder in which `QtCore.so` expects it.

An alternate way would be to [build PySide from the sources](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_PySide) (which is what I ended up doing), but that takes longer - and you sound like you just want to get going with Python and Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed standalone QT package for mac?
Qt for Mac OS X: Download Qt 4.7.4 ftp://ftp.qt-project.org/qt/source/qt-mac-opensource-4.7.4.dmg standalone pyside installation raises same error log for me